# Remove directories when find uses wildcard in middle of path

Tags: bash, wildcard

I need to remove directories (and their contents) in a clean-up routine executed by cron. I'm not sure if I am approaching this correctly. To test to see what would be removed, I substituted echo rather than running and rm -rf. The issue may be that my wildcard is in the middle of a path....??

```
#!/bin/bash

dirsPATH="/images/*/03_processed"

find $dirsPATH -type d -mtime +2 -maxdepth 2 -exec echo {} \;
```

or

```
for i in $(find $dirsPATH -type d -mtime +2)
do
   echo $i
done
```

I don't want to remove the "03_processed" directories, I want to remove the contents of those directories - however when I run either of these, the output includes /images/xxxx/03_processed

```
/images/aaaa/03_processed
/images/aaaa/03_processed/761010184884
/images/aaaa/03_processed/79171833116
/images/aaaa/03_processed/873705734964
/images/aaaa/03_processed/997297772672
/images/bbbb/03_processed
/images/bbbb/03_processed
```

I've tried with a trailing "/" in the variable definition, and also in the command using "$dirsPATH/"...

Any ideas would be appreciated - thanks

Comment: Worth a read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs (the guidelines apply to parsing `find` output the way you're doing it, too).

Comment: Try testing any solution you come up with against filenames with spaces, btw -- that'll help flush out some common bugs (that can impact more than just spaces in practice). Incidentally, the `for i in $(find ...)` issue is also part of BashPitfalls #1 -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls -- and covered in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to remove the contents of directories, testing with `echo` was a very good idea.

Your first examples, however, use `find` commands which will necessarily include those directories.

One solution might be to use `-mindepth`, as hek2mgl suggests. Another might be just to use bash's own pathname expansion.

```
echo /images/*/03_processed/*/
```

If this list matches what you think should be deleted (notwithstanding `-mtime`), use that for `find`:

```
find /images/*/03_processed/*/ -mtime +2 -maxdepth 0 -type d -ls
```

And of course, when you're ready, replace `-ls` with `-exec rm -rfv {} \;` or the like.

**NOTE** the `-mtime +2` limit is being applied in all these cases to THE DIRECTORY, not its contents. It is possible that files could be updated within these directories, or files or directories created in contained directories, without the last-modified time being affected on the parent directory.  To demonstrate this:

```
$ mkdir foo; stat foo | grep ^Mod
Modify: 2016-01-12 11:58:37.219228265 -0500
$ sleep 5; mkdir foo/bar; stat foo | grep ^Mod
Modify: 2016-01-12 11:58:42.581329442 -0500
$ sleep 5; mkdir foo/bar/baz; stat foo | grep ^Mod
Modify: 2016-01-12 11:58:42.581329442 -0500
$
```

Note that the final directory creation (`baz`) did not affect the modified time of `foo`.

Comment: Might as well suggest `-exec ... {} +`, as it's been POSIX-standardized for quite some time.

Comment: Charles, thanks for the feedback. The `-ls` wasn't for portability, it was for risk mitigation in case he matches more than he expects.  Sure, `-exec echo {} \;` works too.

Comment: I was actually referring to the final `-exec rm -rfv {} \;`, not the `-ls` -- no point to invoking more `rm` instances than needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-mindepth` option of `find`:

```
find $dirsPATH -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +2 -exec echo {} \;
```

Btw, if you just test which files will be found before actually using the `-exec` option, simply omit it. Printing the file name is the default behaviour:

```
find $dirsPATH -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +2
```